# Entity Framework repository which calls functions on DbContext directly

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository, repository-pattern

One of our developers has built a new project, and I'm now doing some work on it in his absence. I've discovered he's done something peculiar with the repository.

We're using Entity Framework and, as is often the case, we've got it behind a `Repository` class which implements an `IRepository` interface so it can be mocked out for unit testing.

What he's done is put a variety of methods on the `IRepository` that don't call anything on the `Repository` itself, but instead call down the inheritance tree to `DbContext`.

So `IRepository` has:

```
int SaveChanges();
```

And `Repository` is built like this:

```
public class Repository : MyEntities, IRepository
```

But it doesn't have a `SaveChanges` method. Instead, the call is passed back to the auto-generated `MyEntities`:

```
public partial class MyEntities : DbContext
```

And down to `DbContext`.

I've worked on a lot of EF repository layers and I've never seen this done before. I can see the advantages to this: it saves a fair amount of boilerplate code. But the fact I've never come across it in the past makes me uncomfortable: there is presumably a good reason why this isn't common practice. But I can't see any disadvantages.

So: is this a good idea? If not, why not?

Comment: It's a terrible idea bound to lead to misuse of your `DbContext`

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what your colleague want to do but that doesn't look like a good idea. Because he is inheriting MyEntities in his Repository class all methods of MyEntities will be available on Repository class and that's probably not something you really want.

With his code you can write this:

```
var repo = new Repository();
repo.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("truncate table your_important_table");
```